# Подскажите как правильно написать код php

Tags: php, redbeanphp

использую ORM REDBEANPHP, в общем есть две формы, они были сначала отдельно друг от друга, но теперь появилась надобность их объединить в одну форму, Как сделать это по человечески?

```
 <?php
    // Создаем переменную для сбора данных от пользователя по методу POST
    $data = $_POST;
    
    // Пользователь нажимает на кнопку "Зарегистрировать" и код начинает выполняться
    if(isset($data['finish'])) {
    
       
    
      $id = 1;
    // Загружаем объект с ID = 1
    $book = R::load('zayavka', $id);
    // Обращаемся к свойству объекта и назначаем ему новое значение
    $book->status = '<span class="badge badge-success">Выполнено</span>';
    $book->fiovod = $data['fiovod'];
    $book->car = $data['car'];
    $book->nomera = $data['nomera'];
    $book->comment = $data['comment'];
    $book->factobiem = $data['factobiem'];
    $book->timeclose = $data['timeclose'];
    // Сохраняем объект
    R::store($book);
        
        
    }
    
    ?>
<form  action="zayavka-item-1.php" method="post">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card card-primary">
            <div class="card-header">
              <h3 class="card-title">Выполнение работ</h3>

   
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
           <form action="zayavka-item-1.php" method="post">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Фио водителя</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fiovod" id="fiovod" value="" >
        
</div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Марка а/м</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="car" id="car" value="" >
        
        
        </div>


        <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Гос. номер</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nomera" id="nomera" value="" >
        
        
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Комментарий</label>
        <textarea rows="5" placeholder="Напишите комментарий если есть что передать клиенту" class="form-control" name="comment" id="comment" value="" ></textarea>
        
</div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Фактический объем</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="factobiem" id="factobiem" value="" >
        
        
        </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
        <label>Дата и время выполнения</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="timeclose" id="timeclose" value="" >
        
        
        </div>
        
            
            <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-top:50px">
        
            <button class="btn btn-success float-right" name="finish" type="submit">Выполнить</button>      </div>
        </div>
        
        
        </form>


            </div>
            <!-- /.card-body -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.card -->
        </div>
      
      </div>

        </form>
```

а это форма загрузки фотографии

```
  <?php
     $data = $_POST;
    if($_FILES["filename"]["size"] > 1024*3*1024)
       {
         echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
         exit;
       }
       // Проверяем загружен ли файл
       if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"]))
       {
         // Если файл загружен успешно, перемещаем его
         // из временной директории в конечную
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["filename"]["tmp_name"], "avatar/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"]);
       $data = $_POST;
       $id = $_SESSION['logged_user']->id;
       $user = R::load('users', $id);
       $user->filename = "avatar/".$_FILES["filename"]["name"];
       R::store($user);
       
       } else {
          echo("Ошибка загрузки файла");
       }
        ?>
     <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <input class="circle_img_profile" type="file" name="filename" onchange="this.form.submit ()"><br> 
        </form>
```

Comment: Три полезных совета: 1. Не надо использовать редбин, эта программа написана сумасшедшим а рекламируется жуликом. 2. *Не стоит*, право, разрешать заливать РНР файлы к себе на сайт. 3. Не надо думать что Stack Overflow это сервис по бесплатному написанию программ, где надо только оставить заказ. Надо сесть за учебники, и начинать учить программирование. Чтобы понимать что делает хотя бы свой собственный код. Тогда и проблемы "объединить формы" не возникнет

Comment: @Ипатьев про 1 и 2 я слышал, но мне надо было резко поднимать маленький сервис внутри компании, в бюджете всегда нужно вчера, поэтому скорость работы мне была важна и для таких несерьезных задач она вполне себе подходит. Я конечно читаю документацию, но пока нету хорошего понимания, да даже минимального, думаю проблем дял опытных человек написать где как стоит не составит вообще ни капли труда, поэтому и прошу помощи

Comment: На самом деле нет, но я понимаю что Даннинг с Крюгером все равно на твоей стороне. В общем это не важно, поскольку в любом случае заявки на написание кода - это оффтопик

Answer (score 0):

1 в `<form  action="zayavka-item-1.php" method="post">` надо добавить возможность загрузки файла и Добавить поле загрузки файла
получится

```
<form  action="zayavka-item-1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input class="circle_img_profile" type="file" name="filename" ><br>
```

Обрати внимание убрали

```
onchange="this.form.submit ()"
```

2 Скопировать php код проверки файла - в самое начало, тогда выполнится проверка

```
echo ("Размер файла превышает три мегабайта");
exit;
```